# Dynamic JCheckBox names using strings from an array in Java

Tags: java

Hello guys I have searched before I write here. I wasn't able to find something that could help me out, though I am not really familiar with java so I might have missed something.

An ex-colligue created a java program using Netbeans.

These are just some of the lines for the checkboxes (they are more than 40) for only this window. And there are always more.

```
ck01 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
ck02 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
ck03 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
ck04 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
ck05 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
ck06 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
ck07 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
ck08 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
ck09 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
ck10 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
```

I managed to pull videos using an array so I thought I could use a `for` in order to create the checkboxes as well.

```
String [] checks = {"ck01", "ck02", "ck03", "ck04", "ck05", "ck06", "ck07", "ck08", "ck09", "ck10", "ck11", "ck12", "ck13", "ck14", "ck15", "ck16", "ck17", "ck18", "ck19", "ck20", "ck21", "ck22", "ck23", "ck24", "ck25", "ck26", "ck27", "ck28", "ck29", "ck30", "ck31", "ck32", "ck33", "ck34", "ck35", "ck36", "ck37", "ck38", "ck39", "ck40", "ck41", "ck42", "ck43", "ck44", "ck45", "ck46", "ck47", "ck48", "ck49"};
        for (int l = 0; l < checks.length; l++){
            checks[l] = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        }
```

I have added this but I am getting an error `incompatible types: JCheckBox cannot be converted to String` is there a way to edit the code or should I leave it as it is?
It seems to be different from php sadly

Comment: You should be creating an array of JCheckBox

Comment: In Java, you can't dynamically declare variables from strings. I don't know [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) but I do know that it is a scripting language whereas Java is not. Hence you cannot do things in Java that you can in PHP. You can create a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) where the "key" is a string, e.g. `ck01` and the "value" is a [JCheckBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) or you could simply create an array of `JCheckBox` and access each one via its [array] index.

Comment: yeah @Abra in php it's easy, you use `${"Variable_name".5}` and it's done :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array or a List for the labels, and another one for the checkboxes. For example:

```
String[] checkboxLabels = {"ck01", "ck02", "ck03", "ck04"};
JCheckBox[] checkboxes = new JCheckBox[checkboxLabels.length];

for (int i = 0; i < checkboxLabels.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i] = new JCheckBox(checkboxLabels[i]);
}
```